# Table Joins in MapReduce - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop and writing my first program to join the following two tables in MapReduce.

First Table:

```
11111   John
22222   Robert  
33333   Stephan
44444   Peter
55555   Andersen
```

Second Table:

```
11111   Washington    EEE   2011
22222   Jacksonville  EIE   2010
33333   Minneapolis   ECE   2012
44444   Cheyenne      CSE   2013
55555   Detroit       IT    2014
```

I have uploaded the above two text files to HDFS by using Hue. There is a tab space in between each column.
After running the code, I'm getting an unexpected output as follows:

```
11111   John    Washington  EEE 2011        
22222   Jacksonville    EIE 2010        Robert  
33333   Stephan Minneapolis ECE 2012        
44444   Cheyenne    CSE 2013        Peter   
55555   Andersen    Detroit     IT  2014
```

I couldn't figure out what was wrong with my code. Here is my java code:

DriverClass:

```
public class DriverClass extends Configured{

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

    Job job = new Job();

    job.setJarByClass(DriverClass.class);


    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, MapperClassOne.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, MapperClassTwo.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

    job.setReducerClass(ReducerClass.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 : -1);

}
}
```

MapperClass for my first data set(first table) - MapperClassOne:

```
public class MapperClassOne extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");


    context.write(new Text(line[0]), new Text(line[1]));
}
}
```

MapperClass for my second data set(second table) - MapperClassTwo:

```
public class MapperClassTwo extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");

    String temp = "";
    for(int i=1; i<line.length; i++){
        temp += line[i] + "\t";
    }

    context.write(new Text(line[0]), new Text(temp));
}
}
```

ReducerClass:

```
public class ReducerClass extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    Iterator<Text> iter = values.iterator();

    String temp = "";
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        temp += iter.next().toString() + "\t";
    }

    context.write(key, new Text(temp));

}
}
```

Please help me and also suggest me if there is any better way to perform the table joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reducer,the values for a key are not sorted unless you implement secondary sorting. With current implementation , value for a key may come in arbitrary order. You need to add an identifier to your mapper values to identify the value source for a key in reducer.

Refer to  : http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html
http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2012/05/hadoop-genericwritable-sample-usage/